# WCF service call method through URL

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, http, iis

I have an WCF service hosted in IIS. I want to call a method called "hello" like so:

> localhost:port/Service1.svc/hello

My Service1.svc file:

```
namespace WcfService2
{
   public class Service1 : IService1
   {
   public String hello()
      {
         return "Hello!";
      }
   }
}
```

My Service contract file:

```
namespace WcfService2
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        String hello();
    }
}
```

My Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
         <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="WcfService2.Service1">
            <endpoint address="Get" behaviorConfiguration="behavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1" />
        </service>
    </services> 
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

But when i lookup the given URL, i get a blank page. How would i go about doing this?